# Angular (2+): Image references in SCSS are copied into root directory of dist (build)

Tags: angular, build, sass

Every referenced image in SCSS like `background-image: url(#{$path})` are copied into the dist directory of the build.

Example:

```
src:
|- styles
   |- flags
      |- flags.scss
      |- en.svg
      |- de.svg
      |- cn.svg
```

(it does not matter if I use the assets folder. Same behavior. And I don't want all flag files in the build, only the selected by scss references.)

```css
@mixin flag-icon($country) {
  .flag-icon-#{$country} {
     background-image: url(./styles/flags/#{$country}.svg);
  }
}

@include flag-icon(en);
@include flag-icon(de);
```

After build:

```
dist (root of build)
|- assets
|- index.html
|- ...
|- en.<hash>.svg
|- de.<hash>.svg
```

On build the compiler needs the files which are referenced. This is ok, but I wan't to set a output path for these files. Currently it copies the into the root directory of dist. I want it in a subfolder. Not the assets folder, because it is also copied during the build process and I don't want any conflicts (overwrites). I want the flags in a subfolder "flags" or "img-ref". Or embed it into the build files (js/css).

Expected build output:

```
dist (root of build)
|- assets
|- ref
|  |- en.<hash>.svg
|  |- de.<hash>.svg
|- index.html
|- ...
```

How to config the Angular compiler to copy images references into a subfolder instead of the root directory?

[Angular 7.2.1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this line:
`"resourcesOutputPath": "flags"`
in angular.json file.
Or use --resourcesOutputPath="flags" flag on command line.